# Notepad++ regular repression, regular find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a datebase textfile, values are separated with ","

> 2214,Bunny_Band,Bunny
>   Band,4,20,,100,,**2**,,0,0xFFFFFFFF,7,2,***1024***,,0,1,15,{},{},{}

and I would change the 9th value to 0 where 15th value is 1024

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^,]*,){8}\K[^,]*(?=(?:,[^,]*){5},1024,)`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:[^,]*,){8}     # non capture group, 0 or more non comma followed by comma, must appear 8 times
  \K                # forget all we have seen until this position
  [^,]*             # 0 or more non comma
  (?=               # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    (?:,[^,]*){5}       # 5 times a comma followed by 0 or more non comma
    ,1024,              # number 1024 surounded by comma
  )                 # end lookahead
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find: `band[,0-9]{12}\K\d`
Replace with: `0`